# Using a domain between 2 azure webapps

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

Is it possible to have 2 webapps, one for QA and one for prod.

But both running on the same domain, with the only difference being a subdomain?

example:

```
dev.mywebsite.com (Qa env)
```

and

```
mywebsite.com (Prod env)
```

Is there a tutorial somewhere I can use to achieve this? The domain is on godaddy.

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to [Publish Apps under different subdomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/441392/publish-apps-under-different-subdomains.html) , [Subdomain Azure WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640718/subdomain-azure-webapp) and [Setup Custom Domain for Azure App Service](https://pvsingh.medium.com/setup-custom-domain-for-azure-app-service-872eace396b4)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thanks a ton. Got it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible ,as suggested by @Deep Dave-MT, You can surely deploy 2 webapplication with the same domain name with one application being deployed with the subdomain .

Since your website `mywebsite.com` is hosted publicly with  **GoDaddy** You need to add a "A" Host record with Subdomain name i.e `dev.mywebsite.com` in your public DNS. By doing so you would be able to assign the same public IP address to this QA website which is assigned to your production domain name.
But your website will be redirected to the correct application based on the DNS records published in your `GoDaddy` account .
[image]

For more information please refer to this MS Q&A: [*deploy multiple websites to Azure Web App and have custom DNS address for each website*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/416350/deploy-multiple-websites-to-azure-web-app-and-have.html).